# How to get notification of child CListViewCtrl receiving focus?

Tags: winapi, wtl

Using WTL, I have a parent window with two `CListViewCtrl` child windows. I need to detect when a `CListViewCtrl` gets the focus. I tried handling `WM_COMMAND`, and checking if `LBN_SETFOCUS` is sent, but I don't get any messages for that.

Maybe clicking in a `CListViewCtrl` doesn't cause it to "get focus", but I'm not sure how to know which `CListViewCtrl` is currently active, ie if I have an item selected in one list, and then I click on the other list, the first list keeps its selection, but it is now a lighter color.

The issue is, if I select an item in listview A, then select an item in listview B, if I go back and click on the selected item in listview A, I don't get a `LVN_ITEMCHANGED` message because the selected item did not change.

Any way to make this work without having to subclass `CListViewCtrl`, and handling the `WM_SETFOCUS` to send a custom message to the parent? That seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`LBN_SETFOCUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-setfocus) is a **ListBox** notification. The equivalent **ListView** notification is [`NM_SETFOCUS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-setfocus-list-view-), which is delivered in `WM_NOTIFY`, not in `WM_COMMAND`.